# How to take a screenshot of Android's VideoView from rtsp streaming?

Tags: android, screenshot, android-videoview, rtsp

```
v = new VideoView(this){
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        setMeasuredDimension(vWi,vHe);
    }
};

v.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("rtsp://xxxxxxxxx"));
v.requestFocus();
v.start();
```

How to take a screenshot?
I try take screenshot, but picture is black.