# Taking screenshot for videoview and image view in one layout in android

Tags: android, textview, imageview, screenshot, android-videoview

I am developing an app,which is having three views in a layout, for example image view ,textview and videoview am able to get the screenshot for the layout , but in that for videoview iam getting blank .please help me to find out this thanks ....

Comment: Just specify that how are you loading your video from raw folder or from server??

Comment: i am loading video and images from sdcard

Comment: means ur video is not loaded in video view?

Comment: Piyush am loading video in video view only , am loading two views at a time

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MediaMetadataRetriever to create a screenshot of the given frame. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html

Basially You have to create the receiver and set your video as dataSource

```
mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource("yourVideo.mp4");
```

To receive the screenshot:

```
Bitmap bmFrame = mediaMetadataRetriever
                .getFrameAtTime(currentPosition * 1000); // unit in
                                                            // microsecond
```

For a detailed example take a look here: [How to take a screenshot of Android's VideoView from rtsp streaming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24990002/how-to-take-a-screenshot-of-androids-videoview-from-rtsp-streaming)

Or here: http://android-er.blogspot.de/2013/05/get-current-frame-in-videoview-using.html

Comment: I tried with is example in my app i am creating two views at a time one is video and image it will run in loop

Comment: Please specify whats not working. What's wrong with this example?

Comment: Hi Zerd1984, here my requirement is to capture application screen

Comment: what is playing currently it maybe video, or image or both

Comment: How is the screenshot taken? by pressing a button in your application or by using the android default functionality?

Comment: i am taking screenshot using "os.write(("/system/bin/screencap -p "+ filepath).getBytes("ASCII"));" my app is only for rooted devices

Comment: am not pressing any button form background service iam taking  the screenshot and it will save save to sdcard

Comment: Ok, I think this is not possible. I thought you might be able to react on a broadcast receiver for a screenshot, unfortunatelly there is no such event.